# Can I use pattern matching on a dynamically constructed local tuple?

Tags: c#, .net, pattern-matching

This example code doesn't compile:

```cs
record Thing(List<int> xs, List<int> ys);

    int DoStuff(Thing thing)
    {
        return (thing.xs, thing.ys) switch
        {
            xs.Count > 5 => xs.First(),
            ys.Count > 5 => ys.Last(),
            xs.Count + ys.Count > 5 => xs.First()+ys.Last(),
            (xs.Count > 0, ys.Count > 0) => Math.Max(xs.First(),ys.Last()),
            _ => -1
        }; 
    }
```

Does C# (.Net 6 or .Net 7) provide a syntax to do what I'm trying here or is this pushing the pattern matching syntax too far?

I thought I'd got somewhere using the `{}` syntax (relational patterns?) but this still doesn't work since capturing the return value is out of context.

```cs
return (thing.xs, thing.ys) switch
{
    {xs.Count: > 5} => xs.First(),
    {ys.Count: > 5} => ys.Last(),
    {xs.Count + ys.Count: > 5} => xs.First()+ys.Last(),
    {xs.Count: > 0 , ys.Count: > 0) => Math.Max(xs.First(),ys.Last()),
    _ => -1
};
```

It seems like I'm getting closer, but only by trial and error without really understanding the language syntax.

Comment: Are the object properties/fields you're switching on known at compile time (as, bs, xs, ys)? Why do `(thing.xs, thing.ys) switch` rather than switching on the whole Thing object?

Comment: This does not compile since `as` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes sorry I pasted the wrong version, fixed.

Comment: @gunr2171 I don't really understand your suggestion. Could you provide an answer demonstrating?

Comment: There's [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cvp6NG), which is just a variation of Olivier's answer, but I still don't understand what you're trying to accomplish if Olivier's answer wasn't what you're after.

Comment: @gunr2171 I want to pattern match on `xs` & `ys` generally. I might want other conditions than just `Count`, I might want to return an object... let me try to edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could switch on a tuple containing the counts and use tuple patterns. (I renamed `as` and `bs` to `a` and `b` since `as` is a reserved keyword):

```cs
int DoStuff(Thing thing)
{
    return (thing.a.Count, thing.b.Count) switch {
        ( > 5, _) => thing.a.Count,
        (_, > 5) => thing.b.Count,
        _ when thing.a.Count + thing.b.Count > 5 => thing.a.Count + thing.b.Count,
        ( > 0, > 0) => Math.Max(thing.a.Count, thing.b.Count),
        _ => -1
    };
}
```

Note that the discard `_` means "does not matter". As an example, the pattern `( > 5, _)` means: The 1st item of the tuple (`thing.a.Count`) must be greater than 5 and the 2nd item (`thing.b.Count`) does not matter. I.e., if you switch on a tuple, you must use tuple patterns.

Since we cannot use an addition operation in a pattern, I used a `when` clause to introduce a standard Boolean condition.

A refinement of this approach is do create a named tuple for further simplification:

```cs
int DoStuff(Thing thing)
{
    var t = (ac: thing.a.Count, bc: thing.b.Count);
    return t switch {
        ( > 5, _) => t.ac,
        (_, > 5) => t.bc,
        _ when t.ac + t.bc > 5 => t.ac + t.bc,
        ( > 0, > 0) => Math.Max(t.ac, t.bc),
        _ => -1
    };
}
```

---

Yet another possibility is to use a positional pattern with nested property patterns. The positional pattern works because records generate a [Deconstructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct#user-defined-types) automatically. A record's deconstructor presents the elements in the same order as they are defined in the primary constructor. The record `record Thing(List<int> a, List<int> b);` generates this deconstructor:

```cs
public void Deconstruct(out List<int> a, out List<int> b)
{
    a = this.a;
    b = this.b;
}
```

With positional pattern:

```cs
int DoStuff2(Thing thing)
{
    return thing switch {
        ( { Count: > 5 }, _) => thing.a.Count,
        (_, { Count: > 5 }) => thing.b.Count,
        _ when thing.a.Count + thing.b.Count > 5 => thing.a.Count + thing.b.Count,
        ( { Count: > 0 }, { Count: > 0 }) => Math.Max(thing.a.Count, thing.b.Count),
        _ => -1
    };
}
```

This approach allows you to switch on any property and even on more than one property. Switching on `thing` these are valid patterns as well:

- `( { Count: > 5, Capacity: < 100 }, _)`
- `{ a.Count: > 5 }`
- `{ a.Count: > 0, b.Count: > 0 }`
  or the same but with a positional pattern and nested list patterns
  `([_, ..], [_, ..])`

So , there many different ways to formulate patterns.

See also: [Pattern matching overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching)